# HT: Do Checkbox using Array data

Tags: handsontable

I understand that you can put checkboxes in HT using data object in Jquery as shown [here](http://handsontable.com/demo/renderers.html).I would like to know if you can make a checkbox cell if the data is in array. The data sample like:

```
var data = [
          ["", "Maserati", "Mazda", "Mercedes", "Mini", "Mitsubishi"],
          ["2009", 0, 2365, 4303, 354, 5814],
          ["2010", 5, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
          ["2011", 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
          ["2012", 2, 2422, 5399, 776, 4151]
        ];
```

Taken from the HT sample.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a checkbox column with handsontable. A checkbox is either true or false. None of the columns/values in your sample data appear to be true/false.

For more detail on how to use a checkbox column, see [example here](http://handsontable.com/demo/renderers.html)

In brief, you need to make sure the column has true/false values like this:

```
var data = [
  {id: 1, name: "Ted", isActive: true, color: "orange", date: "2008-01-01"},
  {id: 2, name: "John", isActive: false, color: "black", date: null},
  {id: 3, name: "Al", isActive: true, color: "red", date: null},
  {id: 4, name: "Ben", isActive: false, color: "blue", date: null}
];
```

then set the column type to checkbox:

```
  columns: [
    {data: "id"},
    {data: "name"},
    {data: "isActive", type: 'checkbox'},
    {data: "date", type: 'date'},
    {data: "color",
      type: 'autocomplete',
      source: ["yellow", "red", "orange", "green", "blue", "gray", "black", "white"]
    }
  ],
```